# Pasting values from one sheet to another

Tags: vba

How do I get data from 'Sheet1' and paste that number of counts in 'Sheet2'.

for example, i have a table in sheet1

```
Count------name    
20----------ABCD    
40----------EFGH    
11----------IJKL
```

I need to paste 20 values for name '**ABCD**' in 'Sheet2' also I want to insert one blank row between each name change.

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service. You say “i need to paste 20 values”; so what's stopping you from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteValues()
Dim i As Long, count As Long, value As String, lastrow As Long
Sheets("sheet1").Activate
i = 1
lastrow = 1
Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    count = Cells(i, 1)
    value = Cells(i, 2)
    With Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & lastrow & ":" & "A" & lastrow + count)
        .value = value
    End With
    lastrow = lastrow + count + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

In this code there is a small problem, sure you will improve it